# How to stop AWS Lambda [Nodejs]

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have a function within AWS Lambda uses runtime `Node.js 6.10`. Lambda runs my code fine but continues "executing" even though the code is completed. What I would like to happen is that Lambda stops when the code is completed. I have my logs below to see if anyone can see what the issue is. Note my callback to end the function returns `success`

`{
  "errorMessage": "2017-12-07T17:50:55.618Z e4a5bb77-db76-11e7-b2e6-514284a81613 Task timed out after 120.09 seconds"
}`

`START RequestId: e4a5bb77-db76-11e7-b2e6-514284a81613 Version: $LATEST
2017-12-07T17:48:55.527Z    e4a5bb77-db76-11e7-b2e6-514284a81613    -L-llvVALjYpyUV0M6EG //gotten from code
2017-12-07T17:48:58.652Z    e4a5bb77-db76-11e7-b2e6-514284a81613    http://www.loopnewsbarbados.com/content/bitcoin-worth-millions-stolen-days-us-exchange-opens-1 //gotten from code
2017-12-07T17:49:01.150Z    e4a5bb77-db76-11e7-b2e6-514284a81613    crisis, //gotten from code
2017-12-07T17:49:01.232Z    e4a5bb77-db76-11e7-b2e6-514284a81613    success //successful callback
END RequestId: e4a5bb77-db76-11e7-b2e6-514284a81613
REPORT RequestId: e4a5bb77-db76-11e7-b2e6-514284a81613  Duration: 120093.31 ms  Billed Duration: 120000 ms  Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 34 MB

2017-12-07T17:50:55.618Z e4a5bb77-db76-11e7-b2e6-514284a81613 Task timed out after 120.09 seconds`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to **return** in the function after context.succeed or context.fail, to prevent further execution.

If you are using callback(null, result)/(err) in the handler instead of context.succeed()/fail() you need to set callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop to false.

see https://gist.github.com/hassy/eaea5a958067211f2fed02ead13c2678

Comment: If you do `return callback()`, you won't need the `callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop` anymore.

Comment: If you do `return callback ()` and you have other callbacks waiting to process for completion, that will break your execution. Better to avoid returning explicitly.

Answer (score -5):

Just put

```
process.exit(0)
```

to terminate the execution.

Comment: not sure this is a good way of doing it, since in the logs it shows that there is an error : `Error: Runtime exited without providing a reason. Runtime.ExitError`

Comment: It is not because it is a hard stop.